# Bug in implementation of destructor in linked list

Tags: c++, memory-management, linked-list

The problem involves encountering a "double free" error and subsequent program termination (core dumped) when attempting to continuously create, modify, and delete instances of a linked list within a loop. Despite attempts to manage memory properly, the issue persists. The linked list implementation, along with the provided code snippets, has been reviewed and adjusted for potential memory-related problems. Additional debugging messages have been incorporated to identify the specific point of failure, but the problem persists. Assistance is sought in identifying the root cause of the "double free" error and resolving it.

terminal output

```
destructor called for linked list
destructor called for node with value 6
destructor called for node with value 1
destructor called for node with value 2
destructor called for node with value 3
destructor called for node with value 4
curr is null
Linked list deleted.
destructor called for linked list
destructor called for node with value 6
destructor called for node with value 1
destructor called for node with value 2
destructor called for node with value 3
destructor called for node with value 4
destructor called for node with value 5
destructor called for node with value -1905974368
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Please find the code below

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "linked_list.cpp"


int main() {
    LinkedList<int> *list;
    while (true)
    {
        list = new LinkedList<int>();
        list->insert(1, 0);
        list->insert(2, 1);
        list->insert(3, 2);
        list->insert(4, 3);
        list->insert(5, 4);

        list->insert(6, 0);

        // list->display();
        // std::cout << "Size of list: " << list->size() << std::endl;
        delete list;
        std::cout << "Linked list deleted." << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

linked_list.h

```
template <typename T> 
class LinkedList
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node* next;
        Node();
        Node(T data);
        Node(T data, Node* next);
    };

    Node *head;
public:
    LinkedList();

    void insert(T val, int pos);

    void erase(int pos);

    int size();

    void display();    

    ~LinkedList();
};
```

linked_list.cpp

```
#include "linked_list.h"
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> 
LinkedList<T>::Node::Node() {
    next = nullptr;
}

template <typename T> 
LinkedList<T>::Node::Node(T data) {
    this->data = data;
    this->next = nullptr;
}

template <typename T> 
LinkedList<T>::Node::Node(T data, Node *next) {
    this->data = data;
    this->next = next;
}


template <typename T> 
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList() = default;

template <typename T>
int LinkedList<T>::size() {
    int count = 0;
    Node *curr = head;
    while (curr)
    {
        count++;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return count;
}

template <typename T> 
void LinkedList<T>::insert(T val, int pos) {
    if (pos == 0)
    {
        head = new Node(val, head);
        return;
    }
    Node *curr = head;
    int i=0;
    while (i < pos-1)
    {
        if(curr) curr = curr->next;
        else { 
            std::cout << "pos value outside" << std::endl;  
            return;
        }
        i++;
    }
    curr->next = new Node(val, curr->next);
}

template <typename T> 
void LinkedList<T>::erase(int pos) {
    if (pos == 0)
    {
        if (head)
        {
            Node* temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;
            return;
        }

        std::cout << "no elements" << std::endl;
        return;
        
    }
    Node * curr = head;

    if (curr == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "no elements" << std::endl;
        return;
    }    

    int i=0;
    while (i < pos-1)
    {
        if(curr) curr = curr->next;
        else { 
            std::cout << "pos value outside" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        i++;
    }
    Node * temp = curr->next;
    if (temp)
    {
        curr->next = temp->next;
    }
    delete temp;    
}

template <typename T> 
void LinkedList<T>::display() {
    Node *curr = head;
    while (curr)
    {
        std::cout << curr->data << "->";
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


template <typename T> 
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList()
{
    std::cout << "destructor called for linked list" << std::endl;
    Node *curr = head;
    while (curr)
    {
        Node *temp = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        delete temp;

    }

    head = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Never include *.cpp files. Don't split template classes into header/implementation files; always implement a template class in the header. Your `Node` probably shouldn't have its own destructor because the list should be responsible for managing the nodes (just saying this out loud, I do see that your `Node` destructor is just logging). My final note is that the list object itself has no reason to be heap-allocated.

Comment: Someone might show up and mention `std::list`, but I like linked lists for learning purposes. Someone else put it better than I will, but they are principle-dense and require a solid understanding of all mechanisms being used. And to me, they mark graduation from my threshold of what I would consider beginner-level C++.

Comment: `if(curr == nullptr) {std::cout << "curr is null" << std::endl; break;}` The `break` is an issue. You leak memory by exiting too early.

Comment: Have you tried just building an empty linked list and deleting it?

Comment: yes @sweenish I was trying if(curr== nullptr) during debugging I forgot and included it in the code here, sorry for that, and thanks for suggestions. Earlier that you mentioned Node destructor is just logging, I don't understand what am I supposed to do there. I am a beginner in CPP specially for object oriented programming

Comment: Works fine when I comment out the while loop in test.cpp.

Comment: First thing first, `list = new LinkedList<int>();` is a Java-ism that is simply not needed in C++. Use `LinkedList<int> list;`. No pointer here.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI no effect the problem persists

Comment: You're missing copy and move constructor and assignment. This doesn't necessarily cause this error, but will bite you sooner or later.

Comment: @Chris that's precisely what I am testing, if memory management is being done correctly then it should have been running fine in loop without accumulating extra space. But somehow it was not happening.

Comment: It is not something that causes your specific error, it is about a general misconception about how objects work in C++.

Comment: One of the benefits of writing classes that use pointers is to avoid having to use pointers outside of the class. But your code uses pointers anyway, `LinkedList<int> *list;` There is no need for `list` to be a pointer, prefer this `LinkedList<int> list;`.

Answer (score 2):

```
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList() = default;
```

This is **wrong**. You **must** initialise `head` to a null pointer value.

Comment: Or `Node *head = nullptr;` in class body. Also `=default` default constructors are treacherous, they may or may not zero your members depending on how you initialize the class.

Comment: I checked it, the problem continues.

Comment: @VimalKumar You checked what exactly? I fixed your constructor and the problem [does not persist](https://godbolt.org/z/x89z3abEE).

Comment: I don't see any issues with default member initialization.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI *"A nice prank, but no, we don't do that."* Wdym? Isn't initialization in class body better in general? You can quickly check that all fields are always initialized, without checking each individual constructor.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sorry misread your comment.

Comment: @sweenish "I don't see any issues". Perhaps there's one anyway[?](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#general-7)

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI What? The generic case of no initialization happening? That has nothing to do with default member initialization, but with constructor selection? Where the issue would not be that members were default initialized, but that an appropriate constructor was not written?

Comment: @sweenish Sorry, now I don't have no greenest idea what you are talking about. Perhaps just a gross misunderstanding on my part.